# XML getElementsByTagName item number

Tags: php, xml

In my PHP file I use the following 2 lines of code to append the other items in my XML file;

```
// add more elements to xml file
    $CustomerDDInfo = $xml->getElementsByTagName('CstmrDrctDbtInitn')->item(0);

    // add this element to the root
     $xml->documentElement->appendChild($CustomerDDInfo);
```

This works fine. But in another section I use the following two lines of code to append from PaymentInformation;

```
// add more elements to xml file
    $PaymentInformation = $xml->getElementsByTagName('PmtInf')->item(0);

    // add this element to the root
    $xml->documentElement->appendChild($PaymentInformation);
```

This messes up the ordering of the nodes. I am very new to XML and I realise its because I have the item(0) in both line but any suggestions on how to fix this?

Id be really grateful if someone could even explain to me what the item thing is about? Thanks.

Comment: maybe use this http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php

Comment: I will have a look at it, thanks for replying, I was beginning to feel like I was being ignored :P

Comment: your problem description is not very clear as well. it's with assumptions and what not and you don't actually say what the "error" is in concrete, what you expected etc.